# Unknown Provider error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created a route config like below :

```
angular.module('kappa.configs',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            getPlate: ['$http',function($http){
                return $http.get('samples.json');
            }]
        }
  });
}]);
angular.module('kappa.controllers',[])
.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope','$http','SamplesService','getPlate',function($scope,$http,SamplesService,getPlate){
  $scope.fullPlate = getPlate;
 // Some more code here
}]);

//Some more code
angular.module('kappa',['ngResource','ngRoute','kappa.services','kappa.controllers','kappa.configs']);
```

But I get a unknown provider error like below:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: getPlateProvider <- getPlate
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/unpr?p0=getPlateProvider%20%3C-%20getPlate
 at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:78:12
 at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:3546:19
 at Object.getService [as get] (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:3673:39)
 at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:3551:45
 at getService (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:3673:39)
 at invoke (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:3700:13)
 at Object.instantiate (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:3721:23)
 at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:6772:28
 at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:6185:34
 at forEach (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js:310:20)
```

I am stuck here .. any help is appreciated ..

Comment: Did you try with `angular.module('kappa.controllers',[kappa.configs])`?

Comment: yes I did but didnt work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will run into this problem if you are trying to use the controller anywhere other than in the context of a `route`, e.g. if you have `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` somewhere in your template or if you are using it another route which does not have `getPlate` resolver.

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/J4thldg3aWmC9e8UAHut?p=preview

If you include `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` anywhere in the template, you'll see the error.

Comment: Thanks, I was using ng-controller directive in the template. But I am not still able to get the data from the json into the controller ? http://plnkr.co/edit/EJm4w4kAC4Pv7ZmPxqdn?p=preview

Comment: @goutham There was no `ng-view`, no `template` associated with the route and the file was spelled `.samples.json`. Fixed here: http://plnkr.co/edit/H7bLcyVmxDEcgCJmJDnr?p=preview